# Copying MongoDB database from server A to server B

Tags: mongodb

Using MongoDB I'm trying to copy a database from one server to another. My first attempt was to just copy all of the files from the data/db/databasename folder to the second server, however that didn't seem to work, as it says there are no collections in the database on server B.

The second thing I tried was to use copyDatabase from server B however it errors:

> db.copyDatabase("DatabaseName","DatabaseName","myserverip");
>   { "errmsg" : "couldn't connect to server myserverip", "ok" : 0 }

I have the port 27017 enabled for tcp and udp for both incoming and outgoing on both server A and server B.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly me... I had created the mongod windows service like so:

```
mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --logpath e:\mongo\logs\log.txt --logappend --dbpath e:\mongo\data --directoryperdb --install
```

When really it needed to be:

```
mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --logpath e:\mongo\logs\log.txt --logappend --dbpath e:\mongo\data**\db** --directoryperdb --install
```

It was looking in the wrong folder for the db...

Comment: seems like answered your own question so mark it as answered. :)